# How to send message from iphone/touch to server(tomcat)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have native iphone/ipod touch application.After enter the infomation on that application it will store into server database,again send message to iphone/ipod.Using objective c how to do ?

Please help me out...

Comment: Already asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018369/accessing-web-service-from-iphone

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly clear on how your environment is architected but you'll probably want to setup a webservice on your server and code something  [like this](http://developer.omniture.com/node/321) .